# ZF2 Injecting a service to all the services by default

Tags: zend-framework2, inversion-of-control

I have an authentication_service, which is required in all the services throughout the application. So, I don't want to inject this service every time (DRY). Is there a way, I can have this common service accessible from all the modules, with injecting via factory?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [service initializers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html), great article with examples and more important with explained consequences:

http://www.masterzendframework.com/zend-framework/easy-setter-injection-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: That article has some problems. Be very wary of setter injection. Also, while more verbose, concrete factories and initializers should be used, as closures can't be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a base service which defines all the common service requirements, such as your $authService property and the constructor that sets it. Then have your services extend that. Avoid reimplementing the constructor and property in every service to stay DRY, but injecting it via every service's factory is expected.